# Can one compute eigenvectors from submatrices obtained by removing successive rows and columns?

Tags: linear-algebra

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795), an 'eigenvalue-eigenvector relation' is (re-)discovered which expresses the eigenvectors of an $N$ by $N$ hermitian matrix $M$ in terms of its eigenvalues and its minors (minors are eigenvalues of matrices obtained from $M$ by removing rows and columns). In particular, to calculate the eigenvector components, one requires the minors obtained by removing the $j$th row and the $j$th column for $1 \leq j \leq N$.

In some cases, one may only have access to the minors obtained by removing *all* rows and columns up to $j$, but not those obtained by removing *only* the $j$th row and column. My question is: **Can one calculate eigenvector components from these minors as well?**  That is, is there an expression for eigenvector components that uses minors obtained by removing all rows and columns up to $j$. Alternatively, can such an expression be shown to exist?

Comment: That is a math paper, and this is a math question. It belongs on [math.se].

Comment: Indeed, I asked this question in a slightly different form there and only posted it here after not receiving any answers. As expressions such as this have many applications in physics (3 out of 4 authors of that paper are, in fact, physicists), it seemed appropriate to post this question here as well.